# Magento - What is the simplest module configuration to allow for sql modifications

Tags: sql, magento

What is the simplest module configuration that I need to make my module be able to execute some sql-queries on the database via `sql/module_name/mysql4-install-x.x.x.php`?
Do I need to define a model? Do I need to define a Resource Model?

I am interested because I have a very simple Magento module (not even a single model is defined) but I would like to add/modify some content in/to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a model if you are modelling something as an object. You only need a resource model if your model is built from a resource. What you do need is the module declaration, a version number and a setup name. It can all be done in just **app/etc/modules/Module_Name.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Module_Name>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Module_Name>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <modulename_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Module_Name</module>
                </setup>
            </modulename_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

The `<modulename_setup>` element means Magento will look in "app/etc/code/local/Module/Name/sql/**modulename_setup**/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php".
A class is not specified which means a `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup` will be used and so will be the context for the install script when it is run.

Comment: Thanks! Even less than I hoped :-)